# Butterworth Nth order filter design

Tags: c++, filtering, signal-processing

I am looking for a function which calculate a Butterworth Nth filter design coefficients like a Matlab function:

```
[bl,al]=butter(but_order,Ws);
```

and

```
[bh,ah]=butter(but_order,2*bandwidth(1)/fs,'high');
```

I found many examples of calculating 2nd order but not Nth order (for example I work with order 18 ...). - unfortunately I haven't any knowledge about DSP.

Do you know any library or a way to easily implement this method? When I know just order, cut off frequency and sample rate. I just need to get a vectors of B (numerator) and A (denominator).

There is also a requirement that the method works under different platforms - Windows, Linux, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be easily found (in Debian or Ubuntu):

```
$ aptitude search ~dbutterworth | grep lib
```

Which gives you answer immediately:

```
p   librtfilter-dev         - realtime digital filtering library (dev)
p   librtfilter1            - realtime digital filtering library        
p   librtfilter1-dbg        - realtime digital filtering library (dbg)
```

So you need library called `rtfilter`. Description:

> **rtfilter** is a library that provides a set of routines implementing realtime digital filter for multichannel signals (i.e. filtering multiple signals with the same filter parameters). It implements FIR, IIR filters and downsampler for float and double data type (both for real and complex valued signal). Additional functions are also provided to design few usual filters: **Butterworth**, Chebyshev, windowed sinc, analytical filter...

This library is cross-platform, i.e. works under Linux, MacOS and Windows. From
[official site](http://cnbi.epfl.ch/software/rtfilter.html):

> **rtfilter** should compile and run on any POSIX platform (GNU/Linux, MacOSX, BSD...) and Windows platforms.

You can install it like this:

```
$ sudo aptitude install librtfilter-dev librtfilter1
```

After `-dev` package is installed, you can even find an example (with Butterworth filter usage) at `/usr/share/doc/librtfilter1/examples/butterworth.c`. This example (along with corresponding `Makefile`) also can be found [here](https://github.com/nbourdau/rtfilter/blob/master/doc/examples/butterworth.c).

Particularly you are interested in `rtf_create_butterworth()` function. You can access documentation for this function via command:

```
$ man rtf_create_butterworth
```

or you can read it [here](http://www.unix.com/man-page/debian/3/rtf_create_butterworth/).

You can specify **any filter order** passing it as `num_pole` param to `rtf_create_butterworth()` function (as far as I remember the number of poles it's the same thing as filter order).

### UPDATE

This library doesn't provide **external API** for coefficients calculation. It only provides actual filtering capabilities, so you can use `rtf_filter()` to obtain samples (data) after filtering.

**But**, you can find the code for coefficients calculation in library sources. See [compute_cheby_iir()](https://github.com/nbourdau/rtfilter/blob/master/src/common-filters.c#L250) function. This function is `static`, so it's only can be used inside the library itself. But, you can copy this function code **as is** to your project and use it. Also, don't let the name of this function confuse you: it is the same algorithm for Butterworth filter and Chebyshev filter coefficients calculation.

Let's say, you have prepared parameters for `rtf_create_butterworth()` function:

```
const double cutoff     = 8.0;          /* cutoff frequency, in Hz */
const double fs         = 512.0;        /* sampling rate, in Hz */

unsigned int nchann     = 1;            /* channels number */
int proctype            = RTF_FLOAT;    /* samples have float type */
double fc               = cutoff / fs;  /* normalized cut-off frequency, Hz */
unsigned int num_pole   = 2;            /* filter order */
int highpass            = 0;            /* lowpass filter */
```

Now you want to calculate numerator and denominator for your filter. I have written the wrapper for you:

```
struct coeff {
    double *num;
    double *den;
};

/* TODO: Insert compute_cheby_iir() function here, from library:
 * https://github.com/nbourdau/rtfilter/blob/master/src/common-filters.c#L250
 */

/* Calculate coefficients for Butterworth filter.
 * coeff: contains calculated coefficients
 * Returns 0 on success or negative value on failure.
 */
static int calc_coeff(unsigned int nchann, int proctype, double fc,
                      unsigned int num_pole, int highpass,
                      struct coeff *coeff)
{
    double *num = NULL, *den = NULL;
    double ripple = 0.0;
    int res = 0;

    if (num_pole % 2 != 0)
        return -1;

    num = calloc(num_pole+1, sizeof(*num));
    if (num == NULL)
        return -2;
    den = calloc(num_pole+1, sizeof(*den));
    if (den == NULL) {
        res = -3;
        goto err1;
    }

    /* Prepare the z-transform of the filter */
    if (!compute_cheby_iir(num, den, num_pole, highpass, ripple, fc)) {
        res = -4;
        goto err2;
    }

    coeff->num = num;
    coeff->den = den;

    return 0;

err2:
    free(den);
err1:
    free(num);
    return res;
}
```

You can use this wrapper like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    struct coeff coeff;
    int res;
    int i;

    /* Calculate coefficients */
    res = calc_coeff(nchann, proctype, fc, num_pole, highpass, &coeff);
    if (res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: unable to calculate coefficients: %d\n", res);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* TODO: Work with calculated coefficients here (coeff.num, coeff.den) */
    for (i = 0; i < num_pole+1; ++i)
        printf("num[%d] = %f\n", i, coeff.num[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < num_pole+1; ++i)
        printf("den[%d] = %f\n", i, coeff.den[i]);

    /* Don't forget to free memory allocated in calc_coeff() */
    free(coeff.num);
    free(coeff.den);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you are interested in math background for those coefficients calculation, look at [DSP Guide, chapter 33](http://www.dspguide.com/CH33.PDF).

Comment: Thank you very much. And is there any way how from `hfilter` get transfer function coefficients B and A? Or I must use `rtf_filter(..)` for filtering?

Comment: I have added **UPDATE** to my answer, regarding coefficients calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your help is much useful for me. Very well explained. Works well.